# How to set document icons for a Mac OS app?

Tags: macos

Hi StackOverflow People,

I've seen the notes and have no problem with setting the primary application icon for a McOSX application.

What I cannot find is the way to create and identify, in the info.plist file, the icon to be used with various different kinds of documents associated with the application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `CFBundleTypeExtensions` and `CFBundleTypeIconFile`.
Specify the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in the `info.plist` for general formats.

- [Apple - Core Foundation Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1)

In case of proprietary data formats, specify a new `Uniform Type Identifier`.

- [Apple - Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html)
- [Apple -  Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1)